# Error retrieving bash value into PHP variable using cron

Tags: php, cron

I have used cron to run PHP:

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/new12345/testing.sh
```

This bash contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q   /var/www/html/new12345/shell_call.php
```

and my `shell_call.php` has a variable:

```
$a= shell_exec("./main.sh $l");
```

My `main.sh` is suppose to return a particular filename which it returns when executed in terminal.

However, when I try to run `main.sh` from this procedure, I find value of a to be `null`.

Comment: further i have set permissions 777 to all associated files...i just need to run thru cron

Comment: Suggestions: modify php script to print value before it is returned to verify the right value; then remove print line. I do not know if you can have a space between =, as in $a=, and shell_exec. Finally, does rc=`/usr/bin/php -q   /var/www/html/new12345/shell_call.php` exit rc
work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at the working directory for the php scripts as the first suspect. try:

`$a= shell_exec(dirname(__FILE__). "/main.sh $l");`